# The use of "está" in the given sentence

Tags: gramática

> The rice lacks salt.

To my understanding I translated the above sentence into

> El arroz escaso de sal.

However, it turned out to be incorrect as I was practicing the spanish grammar. The correct answer turned out to be

> El arroz está escaso de sal.

I did not get much sense either when I tried to translate this sentence to English as it would be something like

> The rice is lack of salt.

So I would like to know what role does 'esta' plays in above sentence? And why the sentence would be incorrect without the use of it?

Comment: I corrected the accent on **está**. This case is important because it is confused with the adjective **esta** (this), whereas that word is the subject of this question.

Comment: @Rodrigo  Would you please tell me how to write the accented words?

Comment: Right now they are properly written. **Ésta** is a form of the verb "estar" (to be), the vowel **a** is prominent. **Esta** is the singular feminine adjective (this), marked vowel is **e**.

Answer (score 7):

Your problem here is that `lacks` is not an adjective, but a verb. And this verb does not translate directly into another verb in Spanish; you have to use a different construction. This is similar to the verb `to like`, which does not translate directly into just a single verb in Spanish:

> I like the sea --> Me gusta el mar (not *Yo gusto el mar*)

In your case, the verb `to lack` can translate into `carecer`. But this verb is not transitive in Spanish; it needs a complement introduced by the preposition `de`:

> The rice lacks salt --> El arroz carece de sal

In fact, `carecer` suggests `to lack completely`; so, if you mean that the rice has some salt, but needs more (and I think this is the meaning here), you can use a few other expressions:

> Al arroz le falta sal
>
> El arroz está escaso de sal
>
> El arroz tiene poca sal

As you can see, you cannot do a word-for-word translation. English and Spanish are different languages and use different constructions sometimes.

Comment: To make a connection between *escaco* and English, you could think of it like, "The rice is lacking in salt."

Answer (score 1):

When you translate the original sentence as

> El arroz escaso de sal.

it lacks the verb. The verb is what tells you the action, and is one of the key components of a sentence. Imagine that I said

> El niño hacia el columpio

Without a verb you wouldn't know if I mean "mira" or "corre" or "camina", etc. I think your confusion comes with the use of "is" and "lack".

To improve the translation, it could be

> The rice lacks salt.

or

> The rice is needing some salt. / needs salt

or even

> The rice is bland.

I understand that "is lack of salt" makes no sense in English, but "escaso" is no verb, that is why you need a verb in "El arroz escaso de sal". The tricky thing is that you "forced" an "is" in your translation into English, making a redundant "is lack of".

Answer (score 1):

```
El arroz esta escaso de sal.
```

This sentence is wrong, `esta` means `this` in female, the word for the verb to be is `está`, also I think that a more accurate translate would be :

```
El arroz carece de sal.
```

In my country (Perú) we usually say:

```
Le falta sal al arroz.
```

You can also say:

```
El arroz está soso. (The rice is insipid.)
```

I think the English word `insipid` does not fit quite well, but `soso` literally [means](http://dle.rae.es/soso): "`that hasn't salt or has a little salt.`"

```
soso, sa.

(Del lat. insulsus).


1. adj. Que no tiene sal, o tiene poca.
```

Comment: I'd generally translate *soso* as *bland* although that doesn't strictly mean a lack of salt, just a lack of flavor. *Le falta sal* is also common in Spain

Comment: I did not know how to write accented esta.